# How to calculate sample RTT?

Tags: network-core, network-discovery

I am new to networking and figuring out that how to calculate sample RTT which will be used later to calculate estimated RTT,

Here's my assigned problem:

Suppose that TCP's current estimated values for the round trip time
(estimatedRTT) and deviation in the RTT (DevRTT) are `250 msec` and `17 msec`, respectively (see textbook for definition of variables). Suppose that
the next three measured values of the RTT are `330`, `400`, and `320`
respectively.

Compute TCP's new value of estimatedRTT, DevRTT, and the TCP timeout
value after each of these three measured RTT values is obtained.Use the
values of `α = 0.125` and `β = 0.25`.

as estimated:

```
RTT=(1-Alpha)*Estimated RTT+Alpha*SampleRTT
DEV RTT=(1-BETA)*DEVRTT+BETA*|SAMPLERTT-ESTIMATEDRTT|
timout=EstimatedRTT-4*DEVRTT
```

i have some questions:

1. How do I calculate Sample RTT?
2. Is the estimated RTT in above formula the previously estimated RTT?

Comment: This looks like a homework question.

Comment: The Sample RTT is empirically derived.  In other words, you actually measure it.   See this for more details: http://web.opalsoft.net/qos/default.php?p=tcp-10

Answer (score 1):

A better way to write this algorithm in my opinion is like this.

```
EstimatedRTT = (1-α)*EstimatedRTT_prev + α*SampleRTT
DevRTT = (1-β)*DevRTT_prev + β*|SampleRTT - EstimatedRTT|
timeout = EstimatedRTT + 4*DevRTT
```

This probably answers your second question. Note that it needs to be calculated in this order because the values calculated in the previous formula is used in the next.

The way it takes RTT samples is by using a timer to meassure the time it takes for a packet to be sent and the acknowledgment for that particular packet to be received again. This means it can take a new sample every RTT. By using the timestamp TCP option, it is also possible to use every ack as a sample.

Source: https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6298.txt

**Edit:** addressed issue raised in comment

Comment: I think the timeout here should be `EstimatedRTT + 4 * DevRTT`

Answer (score 0):

Your timeout formula is not correct. It should be

`timeout = EstimatedRTT + 4* DevRTT`

Sample RTT is the RTT which is given in the question i.e. `330` , `400`, `320` for each iteration
and estimatedRTT is previously estimatedRTT